# Possible to accomplish initial caps on text that's already all caps?

Tags: javascript, css

I have some data(addresses) coming in from an API call. The problem I am facing is that the data is entered inconsistently. Some of the addresses are initial caps, and others are all caps. I tried using `text-transform:capitalize;` but that doesn't seem to work on the text that is already all caps. Is there any way for me to resolve this using just CSS? Otherwise, what's the most efficient method to do this in Javascript?

```css
p {
  text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p>This Is an Address</p>

<p>THIS IS ANOTHER ADDRESS</p>

<p>all paragraphs should be initial caps<p>
```

Comment: No...that is not possible with CSS.

Comment: Should use all uppercase instead. Or just use them as they are...